# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined i am getting this error

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

```
SELECT
    c.CONSOL_INVOICE,
    cu.name,
    cu.CUST_CODE,
    c.bu_name, 
    cLang.name
FROM CONSL_INV c 
LEFT JOIN customers cu ON c.cust_code = cu.CUST_CODE,
    customers_lang cLang 
WHERE 
    upper(cLang.NAME) LIKE ?  
    AND upper(cLang.LANGUAGE_CD) = ? 
    AND c.CUST_CODE = cLang.CUST_CODE
```

This Query Executes Correctly In Oracle Sql Developer but it does not execute in hibernate.

It gives the following error:

> "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined"

I know it's because of multiple columns having same name, but I have done it correctly but still don't know why it's not executing in hibernate.

Comment: Try add alias for colums `cu.name` and `cLang.name`

Comment: Since you know it's because multiple columns share the same name, why didn't you use aliases?

Comment: Also, you really should not mix ANSI joins and comma separated tables in your queries. It is less readable, and more prone to errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others suggested use aliases:

```
select c.consol_invoice
      ,cu.name as name1
      ,cu.cust_code
      ,c.bu_name
      ,clang.name as name2
  from consl_inv c
  left join customers cu
    on c.cust_code = cu.cust_code, customers_lang clang
 where upper(clang.name) like ?
   and upper(clang.language_cd) = ?
   and c.cust_code = clang.cust_code
```

As you can see I've added aliases to the selected columns cu.name and clang.name so that the query result has two different columns.